# Horror movie involving a mirror and someone cutting themselves with scissors

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

So I don't remember much beyond these three scenes:

1. A bathroom and scissors, someone cutting themselves with it.
2. A car where someone gets their neck pierced from behind.
3. A piece of a mirror stuck to a boot at the end.

Does anyone know the title of that old movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Was there a special significance to the mirror? E.g., does the mirror piece stuck to a boot mean that the horror isn't over?

Comment: Did it have any science fiction element to it or was it a plain realistic horror movie?

Comment: @LogicDictates answered the question so the year it was made 1980, looks like it was over (last paragraph spoilers it ;p) and i don't know if ghost with telekinesis counts as sf element :)

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate. As it turns out, I'd asked about this some months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ***[The Boogey Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boogeyman_(1980_film))*** (1980)...?

> *The Boogeyman* is a 1980 American supernatural slasher film written and directed by Ulli Lommel, and starring Suzanna Love, John Carradine, and Ron James. The film's title refers to the long-held superstition of boogeymen beings, and **its plot concerns two siblings who are targeted by the ghost of their mother's deceased boyfriend which has been freed from a mirror.**

This is essentially a slasher film with an invisible, intangible ghost as the antagonist. It kills people by using telekinesis to manipulate objects, and its presence is often indicated by POV shots accompanied by heavy breathing and a steady heartbeat.

Regarding the first scene you described, at around 44 minutes into the runtime, a young woman is cutting her hair in front of a bathroom mirror, and we see a POV shot of the ghost watching her from behind the shower curtain. She apparently senses the ghost and thinks it's her younger brother, so she tells it that she knows he's there and that he's not going to scare her. The ghost responds by taking control of the scissors in her hand and forcing her to plunge the blades into her throat, causing her to fall into the bathtub.

Regarding the second scene you described, at around 55 minutes into the runtime, two young couples are shown having a barbecue on the shore of a river. None of them knows anything about the ghost. As they're packing up to leave, one of the guys gets into his car some distance away from the others, and is killed by the ghost, which pushes a screwdriver through the back of his neck until the tip is protruding about six inches out of his open mouth.

Regarding the third scene you described, at around 53 minutes into the runtime, a shard of the mirror mentioned in the Wikipedia synopsis quoted above gets stuck to the bottom of a boy's shoe. In the closing scene of the film, we see that it's still stuck to his shoe, but it falls off and is left behind in a cemetery.